# NoReverseMatch Exception in django named group url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-1.7

I am new to django and playing with urls and stuck on this problem,
I have a view in my `views.py` which reverse url to a different view

```
def index(request):
  username = request.session.get('username')
  if username is None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_page'))
    #return HttpResponse("Testing view session not found")
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_page', kwargs = {'username': username,}))
    #return HttpResponse("Testing view " + username)
```

now when code will reach to `else` block since `username` is not `None`, so here is my URLconf

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<username>^)', views.profile, name = "profile_page"),)
```

So in simple words I am calling `profile_page` url which is using a named parameter username and I am passing the same from `kwargs`, but I am getting `NoReverseMatch` with Exception Message:

> Reverse for 'profile_page' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'dheerendra'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P^)']

Answer (score 0):

To construct a `profile_page` URL, it requires a `username` to be fully filled out. You're calling `reverse('profile_page')` without passing username in the kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You've given the url a named group `username` but you haven't actually given a regular expression for the named group. You want your `username` regular expression to match a varying length username so you need:

  `url(r'?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name="profile_page"),`

  where `\w+` is the regular expression
- Secondly, as you will see from the examlpe above, you need to terminate the regular expression with a `$` so that urls such as `/myusername/otherstring/` don't incorrectly get matched